# Pass json decode variable to php

Tags: php, json

I have a JQuery login request as follow using Json encode / decode:

```
$('#btn_signin').click(function(){
    var parameters = $('#signin_form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: baseurl + 'site/loginRequest',
        type: 'POST',
        data: parameters,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(output_str){
            if(output_str.usertype == "a"){
                var sess_email = output_str.email;
                window.location.replace(baseurl + 'site/page_a');


            }else if(output_str.usertype == "b"){
                var sess_email = output_str.email;
                window.location.replace(baseurl + 'site/page_b');

            }else{
                $('#result_msg').html(output_str);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

As seen on the script with **var sess_email** how can I pass it to php variable?

Any advise? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I understand this right, but if you want to assign the value of a PHP variable to a Javascript variable you could do something like this:

```
var sess_email = <?php echo $someVar ?>;
```

If your looking for the other way around, passing a var from Javascript to PHP, then this is the way to go:

- Send it to the server using an AJAX request (I usually JSON encode it then).
- JSON decode it on the server and assign it to a PHP variable

Example:

In your case you sended the javascript variable 'parameters' to the server. Then server side you would do this in PHP:

```
$parameters = $_POST['parameters'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass javascript variable to PHP variable. But some workarounds available.
What you are trying to do exactly?